# jQuery off() not removing all types of Events of an element

Tags: jquery, events, removeall

How to remove all types of Events of an element which was applied by different methods and selector, let's take an example:

```
<a href="#" id="test" class="testclass anotherclass"> Click me</a>
```

If i attach different types of events on the above element with different selector and then remove by off() function it will not remove all type of events. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#test', function() {
        alert('Id clicked!!');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.testclass', function() {
        alert('testy class clicked!!');
    });

    $('.anotherclass').off().on('click', function() {
        alert('All events removed, except this one!!');
    });
});
```

Is there any simple way to remove all types of events of that element with one selector? Is this possible?

Comment: forget about that new on('click'...) if you just use off() it will still through the others, as we know the off() require to use the same selector which was use for on(). But i am in searching for easy way to remove all types of events of an element.

Comment: `$('body').off('click', '**');` but this will basically remove everything, except `$('.anotherclass')`  ;)

Comment: Yes, but i want for specific element events.